# Problems after moving from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: usb, toshiba

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a [Toshiba Satellite C50-A-1HV](http://es.dynabook.com/discontinued-products/satellite-c50-a-1hv/) and it doesn't detect any USB device (tried with mouse, HDD and memory stick). With Windows, USB devices worked OK.

I used an image DVD that I had also used in a brand new HP laptop where I have no problems.

Is Windows what makes the difference?
Any idea on what the cause of the problem is?

Here is the `lsusb` output:

[image: lsusb output]

Comment: Is the USB socket you used on your PC red (USB 3.1 Gen 2), blue USB 3.0), white (USB 2.0), yellow (2.0 w/ extra power supplied), or black (USB 1.0)?  USB3 devices can sometimes require using a special driver, you see. Also, what is the model number of your Toshiba printed on the serial number sticker? (i3-3110M is an Intel CPU https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/65700/intel-core-i3-3110m-processor-3m-cache-2-40-ghz.html, not a Toshiba model number). Please click [edit] and add that useful information.

Comment: I'm a little bit ashamed. There was a short circuit in a USB socket of the PC. Thanks to your question about USB versions I revised the PC USB sockets and found it. So, indirectly, you have been very helpful. Thanks a lot. This post can be closed, how?

Comment: Resolved, HW fault, there was a short in one of the USB ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, HW fault, there was a short in one of the USB ports.